# How to make users come back to a particular activity after they kill the app

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app, so basically, when the user launches the app for the first time, activity A comes up, which asks the user for a bunch of data. Now, that I have the data, I take the user to activity B. Here, if the user kills the app completely, and relaunches it, the app reopens activity A, instead of B... Is there a way to control this behaviour? I want to be able to control what activity the app should open after a particular action by the user... Note : I am a complete newbie, so I have no idea how to do this.. I tried to ask this up on a google search, but couldn't find anything proper ig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store boolean by shared preference to do that. Here your AcitivityA class. Store user provided data before user land to ActivityB.

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

private SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    try {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean firsttimeLoad = prefs.getBoolean("first_time_load", true);
        if (!firsttimeLoad) {
            sendToB();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("first_time_load", false);
            editor.commit();
  //Store user data here
            sendToB();
        }
    });

}

private void sendToB() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
}}
```

Comment: thanks for the help dude, but I basically just ran a while loop in my main activity that runs whenever the user reopens the app.. If the sqlite database is empty, the app will start from scratch, else I redirect it to the activity I want to...

Comment: is this while loop fulfill your requirement ?

Comment: Yes, it totally does!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to use user data in all over the app. Make a separate class for storing user data and make the getter and setter to get and set the data.

```
public class UserSharedPrefs {
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
public UserSharedPrefs(Context context) {
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("UserData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
}
public void setIsLogin(boolean isLogin) {
    editor.putBoolean("isLogin", isLogin);
    editor.apply();
}

public boolean getIsLogin() {
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLogin", false);
}
```

In Activity **A** makes the reference of that class and get the data and use it as your need. And send the user to desired Activity

```
if(userSharedPrefs.getIsLogin()){
   moveToActivityB()
   }
```

Comment: thanks for the help dude, but I basically just ran a while loop in my main activity that runs whenever the user reopens the app.. If the sqlite database is empty, the app will start from scratch, else I redirect it to the activity I want to...